# stack smashing when receiving a single message through message queues

Tags: c, message-queue

I have the following sender:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct message {
    long int mtype;
    int mtext[200];
} message;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // msg queue
    int msgid;
    message msg;
    key_t key;
    
    // create msg queue key
    if ((key = ftok("master.c", 'b')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
    }

    // create msg queue
    if ((msgid = msgget(key, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)) == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
    }

    msg.mtype=10;
    msg.mtext[0] = 1;
    if ((msgsnd(msgid, &msg, sizeof(message), 0)) == -1) {
        perror("msgsnd");
    }
    sleep(5);

    // TODO: uncomment section
    if (msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("msgctl");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

And receiver:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct message {
    long int mtype;
    int mtext[200];
} message;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // msg queue
    message msg;
    int msgid;
    key_t key;
    
    // create msg queue key
    if ((key = ftok("master.c", 'b')) == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
    }

    // create msg queue
    if ((msgid = msgget(key, 0666)) == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
    }

    if ((msgrcv(msgid, &msg, sizeof(message), 10, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("msgrcv");
    }
    printf("%d\n", msg.mtext[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when I run both of them, I am getting

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The above phrase is shown after the whole code has executed as intended but still, it means that something is not right. If, though, I place `msgrcv` in an infinite loop, everything runs as intended *and* no warning is raised. Since I am both writing and reading the *same size* of data, where could the error come from?

Comment: Why are you using `int` arrays instead of `uint8_t` which would make more sense?

Comment: Overall this is rotten pre-C99 API using the "struct hack"... another *nix facepalm API...

Comment: @AdrianMole YES! that was causing the error. I thought I had already checked it and did not work but I must have done something else wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Lundin I am sorry, I don't understand your second comment. But, as of the first, why would ```uint8_t``` make more sense? could you please send me a reference to check it out?

Comment: This crappy man page: https://linux.die.net/man/2/msgrcv says that the function expects `struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    char mtext[1];
};` which in turn suggests that whoever invented these functions was incompetent. Not just because of the struct hack but also because of the implementation-defined signedness of char and the size of long which might differ between *nix implementations. This is all just _slop_ and I wouldn't pass anything but an array of `unsigned char` to these functions, or who knows what might break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/msgrcv.html), the *msgsz* argument to `msgrcv` should indicate the size (in bytes) **of the `.mtext` member** of the message structure, rather than the size of the **entire** structure.

That structure will typically be 4 or 8 bytes (depending on how `long int` is defined) larger than the available buffer, so you are likely writing beyond the available/assigned memory – causing undefined behaviour.

One possible effect of that UB is corruption of the stack allocated for the `main` function; if that function never returns (as when you add the infinite loop), that stack corruption *may* not manifest itself.

Comment: Are there any guarantees that the sys lib is compiled with the same compiler as the application? It would be nice to assume that `long` has a certain size.

Comment: @Lundin Don't know. Your comments on the question seem just about right, to me.

Comment: So maybe a trial & error, pass a zero-initialized buffer of bytes to the function see how much it fills up. Using these ancient libs always feels like archaeology... surely someone must have written a better lib for IPC since this one was created.

Comment: @Lundin Not sure that it matters, in terms of the stack-smashing issue. We can surely agree that `sizeof(long)` will be > 0.